# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) Error after upgrading to Big Sur [VirtualBox]

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, vmware

I just upgraded my Mac to Big Sur and upon starting a VirtualBox session, I get the following:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

I have looked up online and what worked for people was to allow the program to run in Privacy & Settings but I don't see any such option.

Other option is reinstalling VirtualBox but:

- wouldn't that remove the existing ubuntu image as well?
- will that solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to select the Windows 10 ISO image in storage as an image disk, it should automatically boot in your VM from there. The problem is that you cannot select/add the ISO image after you start the VM. My solution was the following:

1. Select Machine
2. Make Sure Machine is Powered Off
3. Scroll down to "Storage"
4. Click the disk/drive name beside "SATA Port 0" (i.e. [VM Name].vhd)
5. Click "Choose/Create a Disk Image"
6. Click "Add"
7. Select your Windows 10 ISO Image (usually in downloads on on your desktop)
8. Select Choose
9. Start VM

Let me know if that works for you - seemed to work for me! It might run a little slow at first but you can fix all that in the setting after you power your VM off again.

Comment: why am I selecting a Windows 10 ISO image on a mac?